# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate method not incrementing document value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to update the like count of job posts in my application using the `$inc` operator and the `findByIdAndUpdate` method from Mongoose. The correct document is being retrieved and returned but the like count for the job post never moves up from 0 and no updates are performed in the database collection.

Below is the code I am currently using to perform the update.

```
Jobs.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id , { $inc: {likes: 1}} , {new: true})
.then((ret) => {
    res.send(ret)
})
```

Job schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let JobSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    student_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    subject: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    grade: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    area: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    accepted: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    },
    tutor_name: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
} , {collection: 'jobs'});

let Job = mongoose.model('Job' , JobSchema);
module.exports = Job;
```

Any insight into what is preventing the update from performing would be greatly appreciated

I have tried using two queries, one to retrieve the current likes of a post and another to manually update the doc with the incremented value. I have tried nesting the queries using `.then()` statements and have also tried the `updateOne()`  and `findOneAndUpdate()` methods as alternatives. I have tried experimenting with the `$set` and `$inc` operators in my queries to see if either of them perform the changes, but neither do.

I am expecting the incremented 'likes' value to be reflected in the database and for the updated job document to be returned and echoed back to the console.

Comment: What does your schema look like? Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema is missing a `likes` field, which means Mongoose will remove it from queries/updates (since it doesn't match the schema). Make sure to add it:

```
likes: {
  type: Number,
  default: 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it did not even occur to me that the schema itself could be what was causing the issue. Likes are now being incremented correctly. Will be sure to look out for this in future :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this (adding [] around update):

```
Jobs.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id , [{ $inc: {likes: 1}}] , {new: true})
.then((ret) => {
    res.send(ret)
})
```

EDITED:

```
Jobs.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id , [{ $set: {likes: "$likes"+1}}] , {new: true})
.then((ret) => {
    res.send(ret)
})
```

Comment: When I do that it produces the error ```MongooseError: Invalid update pipeline operator: "$inc"``` unfortunately

Comment: Edited my answer, try using `$set` instead of `$inc`

Comment: when I do that it just removes the 'likes' field from the document entirely for some reason